# How can I save eshell alias settings when using prelude?

Tags: eshell, prelude

Second day using Emacs.

I've forked the [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) GitHub project and I'm storing my settings in the `personal` folder as instructed in the documentation.

I would like to be able to use my `eshell` aliases across machines with a `git pull`, but by default it looks like `eshell` settings are saved under the `savefile` directory which is by default ignored by `git`.

How can I put my `eshell` alias settings in my personal directory?

Answer (score 2):

eshell saves your aliases to the file specified in the `eshell-aliases-file`variable, This variable should by default be inside the value of `eshell-directory-name` which prelude seems to override. You should be able to override it back to something you can put under VC like this:

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'prelude-editor
  (lambda ()
    (setq eshell-directory-name "/my/eshell/stuff/")
    (setq eshell-aliases-file (concat eshell-directory "my-eshell-aliases"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I wasn't able to get this exact code working, but I ended up just adding this one line to my personal .el file:

(setq eshell-directory-name "~/.emacs.d/personal/eshell")

And that worked great.  I added a .gitignore in my personal dir to overwrite the ignoring of all "eshell" directories as it is in prelude's main .gitignore.